# C: compiler says "incompatible types" in assignment, but they are the same; and something related

Tags: c, windows, gcc, struct, variable-assignment

I just stumbled on a really strange bug/feature of C (GCC set to C11 on Windows).

```
struct my_struct {
    char my_string[65];
};

void foo (struct my_struct * array1, struct my_struct * array2) {
    array2[0].my_string = array1[0].my_string;
}

int main () {
    struct my_struct array1[60];
    struct my_struct array2[60];
    strcpy(array1[0].my_string, "Hello World!");
    foo(array1, array2);
    printf("%s\n", array2[0].my_string);
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile that,

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[65]' from type 'char *'
```

inside the `foo` function.

Why? They are exactly the same structures and data types.

Also, if I modify the function to

```
array2[0] = array1[0];
```

it works. But there's another program I'm making that prints the string as `(null)`. I can't find out why, but I'll try a little more. If I can make a snippet that reproduces the error, I'll post another question.

Comment: What is test trying to achieve? the code as it stands *is* assigning and won't succeed. Should it be a test of whether string A = string B? If yes then "==" would not be what you want either and you'd need to look at strcmp or better strncmp. Or if you need to copy the string strcpy / strncpy.

Comment: My bad. I meant to test why this happens. I'll change the function's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is confusing, but the basic problem you are running into is that arrays are not first class types in C -- you can declare arrays, but you can't actually do anything with them directly.

Any attempt to use an array in an expression will be converted (silently) into an anonymous pointer to the array's first (or zeroth if you prefer) element.  This pointer can't be assigned to, it can only be dereferenced.

So when you say `array2[0].my_string = array1[0].my_string;`, you're trying to assign to something that can't be assigned to, even though they appear to have the same type.  Much the same way as you'll get an error for something like `3 = 5;`, though in that case you'll probably get a clearer error message.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Since the expression to the right will give a value, it's dereferenced, and the right side will be assigned to, so it's not dereferenced. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the assignment

```
array2[0].my_string = array1[0].my_string;
```

the `char[65]` `array1[0].my_string` is converted to a `char*`, a pointer to the first element of the array. That's how the `incompatible type` arises.

Generally, you can't assign to arrays anyway, so that won't work. Either assign the entire `struct`, or copy the array contents over.

Comment: I thought I could assign it because (sometimes?) arrays are considered pointers, so I thought that I would get one pointer to point to the other, or something like that. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Arrays are implicitly converted to pointers in many contexts, but not always. The only situation where you can do something that looks like assigning to an array is initialisation, `int arr[4] = { 3, 17, 5, 0 };`.